# AzureMfaProtocolProvider - UserMessageIfBadReputation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

As part of MFA in a custom policy we're using `AzureMfaProtocolProvider` to send one-time codes via SMS.

For some users we're seeing the following error:

```
{
  "Key": "Exception",
  "Value": {
    "Kind": "Handled",
    "HResult": "80131500",
    "Message": "ErrorCodes: UserMessageIfBadReputation",
    "Data": {
      "IsPolicySpecificError": false
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find any information regarding this error in the docs.

How can I figure out what triggers this and why it was triggered for that specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneReputation service is integrated with Azure MFA to provide a near-real time determination which tracks tracks the usage and reputation of phone numbers as they are used across various Microsoft services.

Any particular browser user agent having the issue, few days back i worked on a similar issue where latest version of firefox reported this kind of issue reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1090554/azure-b2c-unblock-phone-number.html?childToView=1097185#comment-1097185

Also where are the users located who reported this error ? any specific region/country code users reported this issue.

Comment: I believe all of the affected users were using Firefox, will double-check.